# How do I correct overlapping spacing error in CSS when it wraps text?

Tags: html, css, font-size

[image: Problem]

Right now, when I move to a mobile setting, this happens. How do I correct it?

I have tried adding `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` to the header per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16541112/overlapping-text-in-css-how-do-i-change-it). The CSS I am currently using looks like this:

```
html {  
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #61666c;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    border-top: 10px solid #ECEEF1;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #ECEEF1;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

Comment: set the `line-height` on the `h1`, it's possible it doesn't default to `inherit`.

Comment: That solved the problem. Thanks! ... Then, the next question is: why doesn't it inherit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your `line-height` in the `html` rule is hardcoded to a specific value since you use the `em` units. It gets calculated at the 1.5 times the `font-size` of the `html`.

You should not supply a unit if you want it to be relative to the current `font-size` of each element.

So changing it in `html` rule to `line-height: 1.5;` will fix it.

---

So it inherits just fine, but you set it to `1.5` of `16px` (*usual default*) so it is `24px`. Then you set the `font-size` of the `h1` to `40px` which exceeds the `24px` by a bit..

Comment: You are correct. I had thought I was overriding a browser default, when in fact I had a reset being applied that I didn't realize was there. +1